# tRPC Mutation Wait For Data Updated

Tags: python, mutation, trpc.io

I'm using tRPC, NextJS, and PyShell for my project. I'll send user input to trpc and use that info as input to python script. Wait for python file done and return updated data to trpc, then send back to frontend.

Currently, it takes longer for python file to finish, and trpc does not send back the right info to frontend. Is there a way to fix that?

The code below is for trpc:

```
.mutation("upload", {
        // validate input with Zod
        input: z.object({ input: z.string() }).nullish(),
        async resolve({ input }) {
            var msg = ""
            if (input?.input) {
                console.log("-----------------------")

                pyshell.on('message', async function (message) {
                    console.log("MSG: ", message);
                    msg = message;
                });

                pyshell.send(['sent', input.input]).end( function (err) {
                    if (err) console.error(err);
                    console.log("done");
                });
            }
            return msg.length != 0;
        },
    });
```

`msg` is supposed to get updated with info from `print` statement in python file. It shows empty string in `msg` now.

Comment: I have never used pyshell, can you provide a link to the docs? It looks like you need to wrap pyshell.on and pyshell.send in promises for this to work.